# Elementary linear algebra terminology

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Suppose you have an underdetermined system of linear equations $M.x = b$, where $M$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. (i.e, there are $m$ equations in $n$ unknowns).

You can construct this equivalent equation:
   $x = N.t + b$, where $t$ is a vector of parameters for the $(n-m)$ undetermined values and $N$ is an $m \times (n-m)$ matrix.

For example, in the case of one parameter, $x = N.t + b$ is a parametric equation of the line, so I would assume $x = N.t + b$ is always known as  "parametric equations" of the solution. Is this true?

Is there a name for the matrix $N$? Is there a name for the vector $N.t + b$?

EDIT:
I found this on Wikipedia, which answers this question (more or less)

If the linear system $M.x = b$ has any solutions, they are all given by $x = M^{+}.b + (I - M^{+}.M).t$ where $M^{+}$ is the pseudo-inverse of $M$ and $t$ is an arbitrary vector.

I'm not quite sure how to reconcile this with my question exactly, and I'm still not clear on what is the connection between the pseudo inverse and the null space of the matrix.

Comment: Note that the matrix $N$ is not at all unique, nor is "the" parametric equation.

Comment: If I am right, the matrix $N$ forms a basis of the *kernel* of $M$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: That sounds like you're getting close